# Bringing back multiple max on a single column in sql

Tags: sql

I have a spreadsheet with customer accounts and when we get a new account it gets added on using a reference account number i.e. Anderson Electrical would be AND01 etc. I'm trying to use sql to bring back the highest number from each variation of letterings e.g. if AND01 already existed and our highest company value was AND34 then it would just bring back AND34 rather than 1 to 34.

Each account has the first 3 letters of there company name followed by whatever the next number is.

Hope I have explained this well enouh for someone to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

For a single reference account:

```
select max(AcctNum)
from Accounts
where left(AcctNum, 3) = <reference account>
```

If you want it for all at once:

```
select left(AcctNum, 3) as ReferenceAcct, max(AcctNum)
from Accounts
group by left(AcctNum, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're asking but if you need to find max value that is part of a string you can do it with substring. So if you need to find the highest number from a column that contains those values you can do it with:

```
;WITH tmp AS(
    SELECT 'AND01' AS Tmp
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'AND34'
) SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(tmp, 4, 2)) FROM tmp GROUP BY SUBSTRING(tmp, 0, 3)
```

That's a little test query that returns 34 because I'm grouping by first 3 letters, you probably want to group it by some ID.